# Buggy scroll in the opposite direction to the swipe (cordova android webview)

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, webview

I'm seeing an odd bug where scrolling in one direction occasionally scrolls my webview in the opposite direction. You can see in this gif:

[image: gif showing incorrect scroll direction]

You can see it starts scrolling down then scrolls back up - that second part that scrolls back up is the bug, I actually swiped to continue scrolling down. This problem is hard to reproduce so that snippet is the best I could get in a recording. This isn't reverse scrolling because it's only happening in one particular scrollable list in the app, and it's inconsistent. The app is a [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) app so it's HTML/CSS/JS running in a webview, and I use [this webview plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) with the webview scroll [disabled](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#scrollenabled). I'm not sure if it's a CSS problem because I've deactivated all the CSS of the list and the list items and the problem still happens. This is the CSS of the parent `<ul>`:

```
    padding: 12px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
```

This is the CSS of each child `<li>`:

```
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    zoom: 1;
```

I've not been able to reproduce the problem outside the app. Any help/ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have that same problem with Fulguris and Duck Duck Go both are based on WebView. Though to a lesser extent I could also reproduce that with Kiwi which I understand is based on Chromium. I also failed to reproduce the issue with Fulguris on a faster device so I'm thinking is has to do with micro lags when scrolling fast through a page. It could be that it is therefore easier to reproduce on slow devices and heavy web page.

Comment: Definitly triggered by lags due to cpu load or something. After rebooting my device I can't reproduce the issue anymore. Still a bug in Chromium and WebView anyway, I mean scrolling should still work even under high CPU load.